# Buscar por nombre desde un input en graphql?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

Estoy intentando buscar por nombre de character en un input que lleva la solicitud a un query de graphql, pero la respuesta no es el nombre que se manda en el input. Les agradezco si hay informacion que me ayude... En la respuesta arroja todo el array de characters. Gracias..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

este es el query:

````
       const FIND_CHARACTER = gql`
         query findCharacter($filter: FilterCharacter) {
          characters(name: $filter) {
          results {
           name
          }
        }
     }
    `
    export default FIND_CHARACTER


Y este es el componente:

    
   const FindCharacter: React.FC = () => {
   
    const [executeSearch, { data }] = useLazyQuery(FIND_CHARACTER);
    const [searchName, setSearchName] = useState<string>()

    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     const searchInput = e.target.value;
     setSearchName(searchInput) 
    }
    
   
     return (
      <div>
       <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Buscar..."
        />
        <button onClick={() => executeSearch({ variables: {filter: 
     searchName}})}>Buscar</button>
      </div>
      <div>
          {data && (
            <aside>
              <h3>{data?.characters?.results?.name}</h3>
            </aside>
          )}
         </div>
     </div>
      )
    }

   export default FindCharacter


   Estas son las intefaces:

   export interface Character {
    id: string
    name: string
    status: string
    species: string
    type: string
    gender: string
    image: string
  }

    import {Character} from './characters-interface'

   export interface SearchResponse {
    characters: {
      results: {
        name: string
      }
     }
   } ```
````

Comment: ¿Ya verifcaste que el quey `FIND_CHARACTER` este trayendo la información correcta en graphiQL o en algún playground de graphQL?

Comment: Además esto `En la respuesta arroja todo el array de characters...` necesita mas elaboración, ¿En cual respuesta? ¿A que te refieres con array de caracteres? Segun ese input es un valor tipo `string` no `Array`; añade como se ve la `respuesta` y en donde